# PHP - cannot get value when input exists

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to use `POST` to get values from a form. I moved the part out to a test page:

```
<form name="form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="enter something" />
</form>
// following that
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST["subject"]))
        echo $_POST["subject"]; 
    else
        echo "input is not set";
?>
```

The `echo` is always "input is not set" regardless I set the value of input or not. And the tag "subject" does exist. This confused me. Why can't I get the value?

Comment: How do you submit your form :)? magic, voodoo, telekinesis ?

Comment: *Voodoo man, voodoo* http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OEJh2FFUUoU

Comment: Should I delete the question?

Comment: if missing submit button was the reason, sure

Comment: I don't know if you need to delete it, just add all of the relevant code and markup.

Comment: No! What'll happen is when [Stevie Ray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29952739/php-cannot-get-value-when-input-exists#comment48026518_29952739) notices it's gone, he'll come back and haunt us all. For the love of God, *run Sam!* @JayBlanchard

Comment: Don't delete it. It is an important notice for beginners that may forget the basics.

Comment: @sємsєм It just can be avoided by reading a 101 tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You should seperate your HTML form from your $_POST processing. This means that you provide the user a page which contains your posted form and then submit of this form is posted to a (different) page.

For example your form is (on form.php):

```
<form id="form" action="process_form.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then you create a file process_form.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['subject'])) {
    echo $_POST['subject'];
}
else {
    echo 'input is not set.';
}
?>
```

Comment: This is open to XSS injection.